# How do I stub a module method from a gem with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module, stub

I'm using the Curl gem for Ruby (https://github.com/taf2/curb) and I need to stub Curl.get in one of my rspec tests (to return a blank response).

Here's what I tried:

```
o = OpenStruct.new(:body => '')
Curl.any_instance.stub(:get).and_return(o)
```

Unfortunately, Curl is a module, not a class (https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/master/lib/curl.rb), so it errors out when I try to stub it:

`` stock_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `any_instance' for Curl:Module (NoMethodError) ``

How should I be stubbing a method inside a module with rspec?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to stub `Curl.get`, then do so:

```
o = OpenStruct.new(:body => '')
Curl.stub(:get).and_return(o)
```

In Ruby, methods on Modules and Classes are still just methods.

Answer (score 1):

**From curb docs:**

Curb provides two classes:

Curl::Easy - simple API, for day-to-day tasks.
Curl::Multi - more advanced API, for operating on multiple URLs simultaneously.

That means something like

```
Curl::Easy.any_instance.stub(:get).and_return(o)
```

should work.

Actually you can even stub module method:

```
o = OpenStruct.new(:body => 'test')
Curl.stub(:get).and_return(o)
```

And then in your tests:

```
http = Curl.get("http://www.google.com/")
```